# JScrollPane isn't displayed

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlist

```
String test[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "75" };
    list = new JList(test);
    list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
    list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
    list.setLocation(50,159);
    list.setSize(50, 100);

    JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane();
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(list);

    add(jScrollPane1);
```

EDIT: Updated my code as you guys said. Still not working :(

So that's basically my entire code for this list. When I run the program you can see the list. But you can see only the first 5 Numbers and cannot scroll or something like that. That the first 5 numbers are shown is intended, I know.

So what do I do wrong that there is no scrollbar?

Btw, I googled for years so don't come with such an anoying answer...

Thanks for reading and helping me^^

Comment: why are you adding your list twice? Initially in a scrollpane and then again as plain list?

Comment: try deleting this `add(list);`

Comment: When I remove this part( add(list); ) it's completely gone. You can't see a scrollbar and a list.

Comment: the latter "add" actually adds the list to the container I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane()
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);// here u specify layout put the layout what u want
getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);// add to the contentPane
jScrollPane1.setBounds(126, 63, 100, 100);// here we set coordinates x, y width height cause we have null layout
pack();// Size the frame.
```

**NOTE**      You should always provide a layoutManager

so then u dont have to setBounds "hardcoded"

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane()
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(jScrollPane1);// add to the frame
pack();// Size the frame.
```

Also a good practice is to use a top level container to add to a Frame for example, u could use a JPanel

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new VerticalLayout()); // this layout is in swingx package
JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane()
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(jScrollPane1);// add to the frame
add(panel);
pack();// Size the frame.
```

Comment: u have something bad in another part i think.. i put that code in an ide and works for me

Comment: :D .. may be u should add scrollPane not directly to the Frame but adding scrollPane to a Panel and panel to the Frame, so u have one frame and u can change panels when u want ;)

Comment: Suggesting the removal of layout managers is illadvised and only leads to more questions. Layout managers provide an important job and over come some very common and important issues, discarding them out of hand is simply a bad idea, even if that's what the OP started to do. I should also add that pack will size the frame to the combined preferred size of the top level components, which you've now ignored

Comment: yeah, that's why i put, " put what layout u want"

Comment: And then you went and used setBounds. You should have demonstrate the use of an appropriate (and simple) layout manager. Since the op is already messing around with setLocation and setSize, it's ill advised not to be very particualr - IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I tried this as a test app (which does EXACTLY what nachokk suggested) and I got a perfectly functioning scroll panel

```
package seronis.testing;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FrameTest extends JFrame {

    public FrameTest(String string) {
        super(string);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));

        String test[] = {"alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "omega", "zeta" };
        JList list = new JList(test);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        list.setBounds(50, 150, 75, 90);

        JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane();
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(list);

        panel.add(jScrollPane1);

        this.add(panel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new FrameTest("Quick Test");
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without further evidence, it would appear your are discarding the use of a layout manager (or using the wrong one).

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // This is the default layout, but I added it as an example

String test[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "75" };
list = new JList(test);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL);
list.setVisibleRowCount(5);

JScrollPane jScrollPane1= new JScrollPane()
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);
add(jScrollPane1);// add to the contentPane
frame.pack();// Size the frame.
```

Layout managers provide important support to your application and overcome of the most annoying and time consuming issues facing most UI developers from just about any language; simply throwing them away is a very bad idea and should not be done so lightly.

It's easy to think you can do without them; but when your UI becomes complex and you want to support resizable windows (and when dealing with scroll panes, you should), layout managers will save your life.